Ошибка при установке mlagents==1.0.0
Я хочу установить mlagents==1.0.0. Кое как установил, заменив numpy 1.21.2 на 1.23.5. Теперь у меня возникает ошибка при запуске mlagents-learn --help:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\Scripts\mlagents-learn.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\site-packages\mlagents\trainers\learn.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mlagents import torch_utils
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\site-packages\mlagents\torch_utils\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mlagents.torch_utils.torch import torch as torch  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\site-packages\mlagents\torch_utils\torch.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mlagents.trainers.settings import TorchSettings
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\site-packages\mlagents\trainers\settings.py", line 25, in <module>
    from mlagents.trainers.cli_utils import StoreConfigFile, DetectDefault, parser
  File "C:\Users\radce\anaconda3\envs\mlagents\lib\site-packages\mlagents\trainers\cli_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mlagents_envs.environment import UnityEnvironment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlagents_envs'

Вот список установленных библиотек:
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
absl-py                 2.1.0
attrs                   23.2.0
cattrs                  1.5.0
certifi                 2024.6.2
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
cloudpickle             3.0.0
colorama                0.4.6
filelock                3.14.0
fsspec                  2024.5.0
grpcio                  1.48.2
gym                     0.26.2
gym-notices             0.0.8
h5py                    3.11.0
huggingface-hub         0.23.2
idna                    3.7
intel-openmp            2021.4.0
Jinja2                  3.1.4
Markdown                3.6
MarkupSafe              2.1.5
mkl                     2021.4.0
mlagents                1.0.0
mlagents_envs           1.0.0
mpmath                  1.3.0
networkx                3.3
numpy                   1.23.5
onnx                    1.12.0
packaging               24.0
PettingZoo              1.15.0
pillow                  10.3.0
pip                     24.0
protobuf                3.19.6
pypiwin32               223
pywin32                 306
PyYAML                  6.0.1
requests                2.32.3
setuptools              69.5.1
six                     1.16.0
sympy                   1.12.1
tbb                     2021.12.0
tensorboard             2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
torch                   2.3.0
torchaudio              2.3.0
torchvision             0.18.0
tqdm                    4.66.4
typing_extensions       4.12.1
urllib3                 2.2.1
Werkzeug                3.0.3
wheel                   0.43.0

Я не знаю, что это может быть. Я использую Python 3.10.12. Я перезапускал среду, переустанавливал библиотеки. Я больше не знаю из-за чего это может быть. Заранее благодарю  за помощь.

Эти библиотеки точно установлены именно в окружение mlagents?

да, всё установлено в окружение mlagents
